# Synchronize video viewing between computers with matching local files?

Tags: video, sync

Let's say I have a video file that I'd like to watch with some friends of mine in different states. FTP makes it easy enough for all of us to get a local copy of the file.

Sure we could call each other up, load the video paused at the beginning, and call out "3... 2... 1... NOW" to all have us play the video at the roughly the same time. For short videos that might work. For longer videos this becomes an issue as soon as somebody wants to pause the video for whatever reason.

Is there any easy way to set up synchronized viewing across multiple PCs on different networks that all have the file loaded locally? It doesn't need to be frame perfect sync, just close enough for a social viewing over the internet. It'd be awesome if it kept play, pause, and seek commands synced up across all machines. For my friends and I we might only need to sync up 2 or 3 machines total.

Answer (score 2):

**Syncplay** does what you're looking for. It's free open-source software that synchronizes playback by controlling the media players over a network. The media files and players are local to each computer.

https://syncplay.pl/

Answer (score 0):

Not aware of any video player with synchronized controls, so suggest use of the National Institute of Standards and Technology [atomic clock](https://time.gov/) as your kickoff signal. Have everyone select the file to play in [VLC](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html) or your other video player of choice,  connect to the website, and at the appointed time, click PLAY.

If you want a slightly more sophisticated system, use a [remote control app](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_remote_desktop_software) running in multiple windows, one for each Child PC. The Parent PC uses a remote control app to click PLAY on the player loaded up on each Child PC.